# Messagebox button text

Tags: c#, wpf, text, messagebox

I've looked around and it appears that everything can be editable in a MessageBox, bar the text on the buttons ([WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)/C#)

```
MessageBox.Show("Generic Message", "Caption",
    MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning)
```

Is there a way to change the "Yes", "No", "Cancel" text or do I need to write a window to function as a `MessageBox` to accomplish this? (There isn't any problem doing that; I am just wondering if there is a way in WPF).

Comment: check this question and answer(s): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6131103/559144

Comment: It seems you can't customize the control itself but you can roll your own. For example: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/26/a-customizable-wpf-messagebox.aspx

Comment: Are you changing them to another language, like 'Oui'?  Or changing the meaning entirely?

Comment: @DavidePiras No I hadn't, I have checked a few at making a new one but was just curious if it was possible to edit the existing one. Thanks for the link though, it will be helpful if that is the path I need to take.

Comment: @Garry Vass No it's not a language issue. I only want single words on the button yes, no and cancel won't look very professional

Comment: @Oli - in that case, use keyboardP's answer, but you should also take a read of the WPF Page Function, which is presented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741843.aspx and gives a very nice effect if you are using a navigation framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MessageBox buttons - set language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930754/messagebox-buttons-set-language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly. Short of creating your own MessageBox, you could use `Win32.SetWindowText()` as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/a45795a5-f8c6-4e9e-91ab-c9236d335e0a) (convert the VB.NET code [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)). If you don't want to have to deal with native functions, then a custom MessageBox will be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever buttons are offered by the MessageBoxButton enum. If you want something different, you have to write a custom dialog.