# WPF messagebox localization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

Is there a way to change the Messagebox **yes** and **no** buttons text to something else ?
for example - **Sí** and  **No** ?!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930754/messagebox-buttons-set-language

Answer (score 2):

You can always make your own MessageBox. Just create a window with buttons and customize it the way you want to. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting xml:lang='your languagecode' in the window where you call the messagebox from. Maybe that will work.

Edit: Google first hit: [MessageBox buttons - set language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930754/messagebox-buttons-set-language)