# How can I change the language in AfxMessageBox?

Tags: c++, winapi, localization, mfc, messagebox

I have an MFC app that uses AfxMessageBox to display message boxes. The app itself lets an end-user to change the user interface language. On the inside it does so by loading resources using LCIDs (or [FindResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.) My issue is that I can't seem to make AfxMessageBox to take LCID to change the language for OK, Cancel buttons, etc. This also affects File and Folder Open dialog windows.

Any ideas how to do this?

PS. This approach must work under Windows XP and up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930754/messagebox-buttons-set-language), there are no standard functions for this, there's a link to a CodeProject article "[Localizing System MessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox)" with source code for a DLL (it's in c# but seems simple enough to be rewritten in C++) which uses Windows Hook so that you can supply your own text for the MessageBox buttons; there's even a suggestion for [sizing buttons to the text](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox?msg=3114020#xx3114020xx) in the discussion part of the same article.

Comment: +1 for linking to an article that doesn't create their own messagebox. Hate those (message boxes)! I think this will cover for Microsoft laziness and inability to provide decent localization for their OS. One follow up question though -- is there any way to change MFC code itself to account for the hook as described in the article? I link to MFC statically.

Comment: Yes, you could add the code to load the button text and the call to `Register()` in `CWinApp::InitInstance()` and the call to `Unregister()` in `CWinApp::ExitInstance()`, but I would recommend that you derive a new class from `CWinApp`, place your code there and base your programs on this new class, in that way you are not affected by MFC updates and versions.

Comment: MFC updates? Are you kidding. It's pretty much dead in the water :)