# MsgBox MultiLanguage

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, multilingual

I'm having issues to translate, I can translate the Buttons, Labels, TextBoxs, etc, but I don't know how to translate MsgBox... I have this code

```
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Imports System.Globalization    
Public Class FrmLlenguatje
Private Sub btEspañol_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btEspañol.Click

    CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("ES")
    Dim p02Es As New Form1
    p02Es.Show()

    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(0)
End Sub

Private Sub btCatalà_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btCatalà.Click

    CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("CA")
    Dim p02Ca As New Form1
    p02Ca.Show()

    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(0)
End Sub
End Class
```

And I would like to know a way to link this Button Click to the other Form and then try if I can create an If/else statement to translate those MsgBox..

I whish you can help me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know .Net does'nt support this with MessageBox. You can read more here...

[MessageBox buttons - set language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930754/messagebox-buttons-set-language)

Answer (score 0):

I've used 1 label and at form_loading this string to determine the O.S. current language:

```
label1.Text=Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
```

some 3 character languages id are:

```
ita, spa, eng, nld, fra, rus, zho.
```

Then when you create a message box, uses some like this

```
If Form1.Label1.Text = "eng" Then
If MsgBox("Save the changes?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
else
end if
If Form1.Label1.Text = "spa" Then
If MsgBox("¿Guardar los cambios?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
else
end if
```

the yes/no is automatically determined (translated) in your current language.

```
catalan = cat
```